# Realtime messaging framework

Tags: messaging, real-time-updates, supersocket.net

We have been using HTML5 WebSocket in front-end and [SuperWebSocket](https://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) in .Net back end application for real time messaging between two applications e.g. when call comes in a cloud based call center (application 1) it should notify all logged in users in website (application 2). During pick hours we see timeout error in SuperWebSoket so looking better solution which is flexible and scalable. There are many [cloud based realtime messaging services](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/). Should we go for cloud based realtime messaging service? Which is best realtime messaging service? Please suggest.

Comment: your question is too borad but this site is better suited. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry about asking too broad question. I tried adding more detail about problem, if it helps.

Comment: post a simplified example so that people can reproduce the problem and improve the solution